# how to install channels_redis module in django without errors

Tags: python, django

am trying to install channels_redis in Django using pip but so far  am getting this error:

```html
 Building wheel for hiredis (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      C:\Users\Teacher-5F84DF\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7pi2nhv\hiredis_6b689b761b5b44cc87e6dbe9cbaa0597\setup.py:7: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
        import sys, imp, os, glob, io
      c:\users\teacher-5f84df\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:697: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
      copying hiredis\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
      copying hiredis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
      copying hiredis\hiredis.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
      copying hiredis\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
      running build_ext
      building 'hiredis.hiredis' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]
```

I tried installing **pip install python-dev-tools** but dint work.Please help am stuck.

Comment: Did you install "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" like the error message indicates?

Answer (score 1):

You need to dowload [Microsoft C++ build tool](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/).

[image]

Comment: I tried installing Microsoft c++ build tools but nothing happened.error still showing